# VBA modifying inside array

Tags: arrays, vba

I am sure this is a very simple question but what's the best way to multiply everything in an array with say 100, or take square root of everything inside an array, without copying it or a for loop?

Thanks!

Comment: even if you looped through it to do that, it should still complete relatively quickly.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that in VBA.